# cannot find SXMPMeta in Adobe XMP SDK

Tags: c++, macos, qt, xmp

I'm trying to write a simple **Qt Widget Application** that allows me to read and write .XMP files using **Qt framework** && **Adobe XMP SDK** on **OS X 10.10**.

**I'm a rookie and by no means proffesional in C++** *(and have basic/intermediate self-taught knowledge of C++ and Qt, which means I'm dependent on google when trying to do something and sometimes end up using bad habits or code that can be simplified)*

1. I have downloaded and built the XMP SDK from Adobe and built part of the examples

(*for some reason or another I have not been able to build the other ones, but that's not that important right now*).

2. I have built the **static 64bit version of the libraries** (*libXMPCoreStatic.a* && *libXMPFilesStatic.h*)
3. Together with the include folder from the public folder I've placed them in my *Qt Widget App project*'s folder into subfolder *Framework*
4. I have linked the libraries to my project (in my .pro file):

   ```
   LIBS += -L$$PWD/XMPFramework/ -lXMPCoreStatic
   LIBS += -lXMPFilesStatic

   INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/XMPFramework/include/
   DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/XMPFramework/

   PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/XMPFramework/libXMPCoreStatic.a
   PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/XMPFramework/libXMPFilesStatic.a
   ```
5. I have included the XMP in my app (basic app just for testing if I can connect and use some basics of XMP SDK) - mainwindow.cpp :

   ```
   #include "mainwindow.h"
   #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
   #include <cstdio>
   #include <string>
   #include <cstring>

   #define MAC_ENV 1 //don't know why, but when I don't explicitly
                     //define this, then the app won't build

   // Must be defined to instantiate template classes
   //#define TXMP_STRING_TYPE std::string

   //when used, I get whole range of errors, there's a sample at the end of the question

   // Must be defined to give access to XMPFiles
   #define XMP_INCLUDE_XMPFILES 1

   #include <XMP.incl_cpp> //XMP INCLUDE
   #include <XMP.hpp>      //XMP INCLUDE

   MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
               QMainWindow(parent),
               ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
   {
      ui->setupUi(this);


      //this if is taken from the sample code
      //for the SDK, the problem is that
      //my project does not know the SXMPMeta
      //but seems to know at least part of the SDK
      //because at least part of the classes and methods
      //are visible through the intellisense
      if(!SXMPMeta::Initialize())
      {
         //the project does not react to SXMPMeta
         //and does not know it, even though the
         //XCode project I've built from the SDK's samples
         //seems to be ok
         ...
      }
   }

   ...the rest omitted for brevity...
   ```

   **Do you see some mistakes i've made or the reason the SXMPMeta class is not present?**

---

Sample of the errors I get when I try to use `#define TXMP_STRING_TYPE std::string`. My thought is that it has something to do with the initialization of the templated XMP classes

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFBundleCopyExecutableArchitectures", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::IsValidLibrary(std::string const&) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
  "_CFBundleCopyResourceURL", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::GetResourceDataFromModule(__CFBundle*, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string&) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
  "_CFBundleCreate", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::IsValidLibrary(std::string const&) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
      XMP_PLUGIN::LoadModule(std::string const&, bool) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
  "_CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::GetFunctionPointerFromModuleImpl(__CFBundle*, char const*) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
  "_CFBundleIsExecutableLoaded", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::LoadModule(std::string const&, bool) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
  "_CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::LoadModule(std::string const&, bool) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
  "_CFDataGetBytes", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::GetResourceDataFromModule(__CFBundle*, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string&) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
  "_CFNumberGetValue", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::GetResourceDataFromModule(__CFBundle*, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string&) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::IsValidLibrary(std::string const&) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
      XMP_PLUGIN::LoadModule(std::string const&, bool) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
      XMP_PLUGIN::UnloadModule(__CFBundle*, bool) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
      XMP_PLUGIN::GetFunctionPointerFromModuleImpl(__CFBundle*, char const*) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
      XMP_PLUGIN::GetResourceDataFromModule(__CFBundle*, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string&) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
  "_CFStringCreateWithCString", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::GetFunctionPointerFromModuleImpl(__CFBundle*, char const*) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
      XMP_PLUGIN::GetResourceDataFromModule(__CFBundle*, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string&) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
  "_CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::GetResourceDataFromModule(__CFBundle*, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string&) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)
  "_CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation", referenced from:
      XMP_PLUGIN::IsValidLibrary(std::string const&) in libXMPFilesStatic.a(OS_Utils_Mac.o)

When executing step 'Make'
```

Comment: do you use QtCreator?

Comment: Yes. I can't see the component in intellisense.

Comment: What have you built static library with?

Answer (score 0):

`TXMPFiles` is a template. `SXMPFiles` is `TXMPFiles<std::string>`. Following code is present in the beginning of one of XMP Toolkit 2016.07 examples:

```
// Must be defined to instantiate template classes
#define TXMP_STRING_TYPE std::string 

// Must be defined to give access to XMPFiles
#define XMP_INCLUDE_XMPFILES 1 

// Ensure XMP templates are instantiated
#include "public/include/XMP.incl_cpp"

// Provide access to the API
#include "public/include/XMP.hpp"
```